# vba Get error "Path not found" while FSO.CopyFolder gets folder name with spaces

Tags: vba, ms-access, filesystemobject

I get a "path not found" error when I try to copy a directory (*strFolder*) that has spaces in its name. Both folders are exists. How to work around this limitation?

```
Sub foldecopytest()
    Dim objFSO, strFolder, strToPath
    strFolder = "f:\Logistics Manager\Invoice\22000741 KlientID\"
    strToPath = "\\10.224.73.57\Database\Logistics\Invoice\"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
   
    objFSO.CopyFolder strFolder, strToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Put them in quotes.

Comment: @Lundt it's working ```strFolder = "f:\Logistics Manager\Invoice\" & "22000741 KlientID"```. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ending `\` from both of the folder paths.

```vb
Sub foldecopytest()
    Dim objFSO As Object, strFolder As String, strToPath As String
    strFolder = "f:\Logistics Manager\Invoice\22000741 KlientID"
    strToPath = "\\10.224.73.57\Database\Logistics\Invoice"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
   
    objFSO.CopyFolder strFolder, strToPath

End Sub
```

If you want to copy over the whole folder and not just the contents:

```vb
Sub foldecopytest()
    Dim objFSO As Object, strFolder As String, strToPath As String
    strFolder = "f:\Logistics Manager\Invoice\22000741 KlientID"
    strToPath = "\\10.224.73.57\Database\Logistics\Invoice"
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    With objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
        .Copy strToPath & "\" & .Name
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately, in this case, all files from the source directory are copied and pasted to the destination folder, but not the source directory with files

Comment: @AleksandrH. I have improved my answer to include an example of how to do that.